# Interactive device vs. interaction device

Tags: adjectives, american-english, nouns

What could be the differences between an "interactive device" and "interaction device"?

My impression is that when we use "interactive device", interactive is an adjective and just describes the device as a device that is interactive all by itself. For example, a device that automatically recognizes voices, processes the information it got from the recognized voice and reacts accordingly.

But, "interaction device" is a noun for a device that is used by a user for interacting with something. For example, a user uses a mouse to manipulate an object displayed on a computer's screen.

Am I wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Syntactically, the difference is essentially the same as that between a ***car radio*** and a ***loud radio***. That's to say, ***interaction*** is a *noun*, whereas ***interactive*** is an *adjective*.

We don't usually use the [noun adjunct / attributive noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) version if there's a morphological variant of that noun that can be used adjectivally. In fact, I'm tempted to say probably the main *reason* for noun adjunct usages is contexts where there simply *isn't* a commonly-used adjective based on the relevant noun.

By implication therefore, using the noun form in OP's example is "marked" (non-standard, not what the audience would have expected). With more context, we might be able to guess at a possible "nuance" that might cause a *competent* speaker/writer to choose the less common form. For example,...

> *John really shouldn't sit in his room reading books all day. He won't actually go out and speak to real people, but perhaps we can encourage him to use his computer as an interaction device.*

I know it's not a *great* example, but I do think the above tends to put more emphasis on John using the device for ***interaction with other people***, whereas an *interactive device* is usually understood to imply ***interaction with the device itself*** (in my *specific* context; it might be different elsewhere).

---

If you're a non-native speaker it's obviously far more difficult to know how your use of a "non-standard" form would be interpreted. There won't be so many examples, and those you *do* come across may cover a variety of different context-dependent intended meanings. Plus if you specifically go *searching* for non-standard usages, you might end up seeing a higher proportion of "suspect" usages from other nns (and perhaps less competent *native* speakers), which could seriously distort your developing sense of how native speakers usually phrase things.

So my advice is to always use the adjectival form in such contexts if you have a choice - unless the *specific* collocation is one you've often heard (such as a ***sports car*** rather than a ***sporty car***).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between *interactive device* and *interaction device* is that the adjective *interactive* here modifies *the device* as a describer; it gives one of its attributes or qualities, **but** the noun *interaction* modifies the noun *device* as a classifier; it indicates the classification or which category does the device belong to, it answers the question *what type of is it?*.